# How to obtain a subset of a range masked by a boolean NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array, numpy-indexing

I need to do integer array indexing of a continuous integer range `[0, n)` which has values that have to be always ignored.
The ignored values should not appear in the result.
And there is a stand-alone NumPy boolean array of length `n` (i.e., a mask) that indicates whether an element of the original range is ignored or not.

In a pure Python, I would write like this:

```py
def get_non_masked_indices(range_mask, indices):
    return [i for i in indices if not range_mask[i]]
```

For this input

```py
#                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
mask = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], dtype=np.bool)
idxs = np.array([      2, 3, 4,       7,    9])
#                      +  -  +        -     +
```

the result of invoking `get_non_masked_indices(mask, idxs)` would be

```py
[2, 4, 9]
```

This is a frequently used array-processing pattern (especially in graph algorithms).
Is there a NumPy function to facilitate that?

So far, I have come with the following options:

- Native NumPy indexing
- Masking with an indexed mask
- Indexing a masked range

Native NumPy indexing:

```py
return indices[np.logical_not(range_mask[indices])]
```

Masking with an indexed mask:

```py
return np.ma.MaskedArray(indices, range_mask[indices]).compressed()
```

```py
return np.ma.masked_where(range_mask[indices], indices).compressed()
```

Indexing a masked range:

```py
return np.ma.MaskedArray(np.arange(len(range_mask)), range_mask)[indices].compressed()
```

```py
return np.ma.masked_where(range_mask, np.arange(len(range_mask)))[indices].compressed()
```

**An example from an application**

Assume we have a graph represented as a list of NumPy arrays of adjacent nodes.

```py
adjacent_nodes = [
  np.array([1, 2]),
  np.array([0]),
  np.array([0]),
]
is_colored = np.array([False, False, True])
```

[image: graph coloring]

The function of my interest needs to return only non-colored neighbors of a node:

```py
get_non_masked_indices(is_colored, adjacent_nodes[0])  # -> [1]
get_non_masked_indices(is_colored, adjacent_nodes[1])  # -> [0]
get_non_masked_indices(is_colored, adjacent_nodes[2])  # -> [0]
```

Comment: Look at some of the accepted `numpy` answers.  You'll see they usually present both the code and working examples.  You are only show code.  Without running some sort test case it's hard to visualize what these are doing.

Comment: @hpaulj, thank you for the feedback; I have completely reworked the question.